# Predicting time series using `arima` or `fitlm` in Matlab?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, matlab, arima

I have 6 sequences (time series); they all belong to the same variable. I divide each sequence in two parts having 80% and leaving the last 20% for validation. I am doing the analysis and modelling in Matlab.

In the training set (80%):
I want to train on 5 sequences using an autoregressive method having a window size of 1 event in order to model the behaviour of the sequences (e.g. sequences 2:5 = $X$) and see whether I can predict the one that is left out (e.g. sequence 1 = $Y$).

I want to have the model learning by steps. The dependency would be like 
$$ Y_n = \text{sd}(X_{n-1}) + \text{mean}(X_{n-1}) $$

For this I am thinking of using the Matlab function `arima` to estimate the model parameters. I don’t know though how to integrate the modelling of $X$ in `arima` since the estimation seems to be for $Y$.
**Q1:** Maybe I am not understanding well how to use this?

I assume an alternative would be using `fitlm` to obtain the model between the  mean and standard deviation (of all the sequences in the training set) per event in $X_{n-1}$ and the sequence in $Y_n$.

**Q2:** Which of these both methods would be better to take into account the changes from event to event?

In the testing set (20%):
Once I have the model I would like to use it to test its accuracy on the 20% percent left. I understand that when using `fitlm` the best would be to use `predict` or `feval` and for `arima` I should use `forecast`.
**Q3:** Is this correct?

**Q4:** Can anyone point me some simple example or tutorial on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an autoregressive model. Autoregressive series would have $X_n(t)=\dots \theta_1 X_n(t-1)$ terms, while yours seem to have only $X_n(t)=\dots \theta_1 X_{k\ne n}(t-1)$.

Hence, yours is a simple cross-sectional model. Here how it looks:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$$

All you need is to create two new variables: $x_1,x_2$. The first one is the StDev of the other four (five?) series, and the second one is the mean. So, you have

```
y = x(2:end,1)
temp = x(1:end-1,2:5);
X = [std(temp,0,2) mean(temp,0,2)]
mdl = fitlm(y,X)
```

That's it. Once you have the model object you can use its predict function and other methods to get what you want. Read fitlm's help, it has examples.

Comment: Thanks, I explained something wrong I believe. In my case it would be:    X = [std(temp') mean(temp')]

Comment: @Noque my bad, I fixed the code. Your explanation was not incorrect. What you need is a std or mean across the sequences, my code had a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I think there is another bug fitlm should have the arguments reversed. That is fitlm(X,y)

Comment: @Noque, sorry, you might be right, I don't remember exact syntax